# Cannot create inner bean 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory#61f90a1c' of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory]

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat7, ibm-mq, tomcat8

I am not able to run my project because of mentioned error. Please advise how I can resolve my error, I already included all dependencies jar in my project but still getting below error when I am trying to run the project on Apache tomcat 7 server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHyv9.jpg)
MQ version are "com.ibm.mq.version 7.5.0.2" and dependency are attached in attachments.

```
            Jan 08, 2019 12:19:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
            SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumer' defined in file [C:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\new2.3.169.1\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\applicationContext-jms.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory#61f90a1c' of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory] while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory#61f90a1c' defined in file [C:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\new2.3.169.1\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\applicationContext-jms.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiException
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5157)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory#61f90a1c' defined in file [C:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\new2.3.169.1\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\applicationContext-jms.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager$3.run(ComponentManager.java:1241)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager.dynamicLoadClass(ComponentManager.java:1219)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager.locateComponents(ComponentManager.java:330)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager.findComponent(ComponentManager.java:249)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager.access$000(ComponentManager.java:65)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager$2.run(ComponentManager.java:824)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager.init(ComponentManager.java:820)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager.init(ComponentManager.java:775)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.componentmanager.ComponentManager.getInstance(ComponentManager.java:1042)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CommonServices.<clinit>(CommonServices.java:80)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.propertystore.PropertyStore.initialize(PropertyStore.java:497)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.propertystore.PropertyStore.<clinit>(PropertyStore.java:227)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.<clinit>(Trace.java:329)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.<clinit>(JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
        ... 53 more
```

Comment: added more part of logs:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory#61f90a1c' defined in file [C:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\new2.3.169.1\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\applicationContext-jms.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiException
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)

Comment: Please click edit and add logs to your question where they can be formatted.

Comment: "I already included all dependencies jar in my project", can you list out which jars you included in your project that have `com.ibm` at the start of the name along with `jms.jar`, `providerutil.jar`, and `fscontext.jar`.  For each of these please list the version shown in the `MANIFEST.MF` contained in the jar file.  Please edit your question to add all of these details, if you can get formatting perfect don't worry I'll edit and fix it for you, you can later edit just to see how I did it as an example.

Comment: I have added additional logs and dependencies of jar in attachment. Please see

Comment: It would be much better to add the text of the file that you provided a image of to your question.  A few comments, 7.5 is out of support since last April.  If you go with MQ v8 or higher you can reference just two files: `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and `jms.jar`.  If you use a "binding" file you will also need `fscontext.jar` and `providerutil.jar`.  Your error clearly says class not found so I would trust that you are missing something and my suggest is to move to the v8 jars to simplify things.  Makes sure if you do that to remove `dbhcore.jar` as it is no longer required.

Comment: Also note for MQ v8 that the `jms.jar` must be JMS 2.0.

Comment: It is existing project, and same configuration and jar are working perfectly in other machine. I want to run same project in my local machine. But getting this error whenever I run it in my machine. So, please advice Am I miss any jar or something which require to run my project.

Comment: You have my suggestion.   If it works somewhere else and you want to use out of date and unsupported software then duplicate the working setup you must be missing something.